# New page at end of subsection (not start!)

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking

In order to keep everything neat and tidy in my document (in particular with regards to floats floating all over the place), I want each subsection to end with a \clearpage. I originally had the following redefinition for the subsection command:

```
\let\oldsubsection\subsection

\renewcommand{\subsection}{
\clearpage
\oldsubsection
}
```

However, this puts the page break before the subsection heading, which means there is a break between section headings and the first subsection headings.

Is there any way to force that page break at the *end* of the subsection?

Comment: You could issue the `\clearpage` only if the subsection counter is not zero. But first check if `\FloatBarrier` from the placeins package is a better option.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer : FloatBarrier is exactly what I needed! If you give that as an official answer, I'll mark it as the accepted one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could issue the `\clearpage` only if the subsection counter is not zero. But first check if `\FloatBarrier` from the `placeins` package is a better option.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you may not automatically put `\clearpage` at the end of subsections since you don't use anything like `\endsubsection` command. But you may try to redefine `\section` command in a way to flag place after section header and avoid breaking at the beginning of the first subsection of the section, and redefine `subsection` to unmark it. For example,

```
\let\oldsection\section
\let\oldsubsection\subsection

\def\section{\let\subsectionclearpage\empty\oldsection}

\def\subsection{\subsectionclearpage\let\subsectionclearpage\clearpage\oldsubsection}
```

You may also like to add `\clearpage` before `\let` in `\section` definition or adopt `\sectionclearpage` in a way to match `\section` and `\chapter` command.

Also, be aware that this way `\subsection` before `\section` won't work. If you want to, you have to add either

```
\let\subsectionclearpage\empty
```

or

```
\let\subsectionclearpage\clearpage
```

into preamble.